# How to accent the 'a'/second syllable in Oscar?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, accent

If you had a character (male) called Oscar but the emphasis was on the second syllable how would you write that? With a macron on the a?

For example, pronounced Oscarr or Oscaar (with the a sound from 'car') and with the emphasis firmly on that part of the name (osCAR rather than OScar)

I don't want to change the spelling but would like to add an accent of some kind which would make reasonable sense to an English (British) reader.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do not answer in comments. Write an answer.

Comment: Heinlein discussed this in _Glory Road_.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably Oscar is not English.

You could indicate this **and** the pronunciation by using an accent: ***Oscár.*** Accents are not used in English, and can be used in other languages to indicate stress. A quick Google search yields Oscárs from Spain, Sweden, Romania and Hungary.

However, even with this non-English treatment, it might also be advisable to have the incorrect "English" pronunciation corrected by Oscár himself or another character soon after his introduction to the story.

Comment: However, accents don’t mean stress in all languages (and aren’t regularly used to mark stress in English itself). Hungarian has stress on the first syllable for all words and uses the acute accent to mark vowel length, so “Oszkár“ is not stressed on the second syllable.